# How to avoid user interactions in selenium webdriver process?

Tags: java, selenium

I have created automation program using selenium, where chrome driver is used. I have to keep browser in maximized mode to show results to user for 5 sec after process completion. But sometimes users are reading through results faster and closing chrome manually. This leaves with loss of control of program on browser and it is not able to call driver.quit();. As this is important to quit the driver. I am thinking of avoiding user interaction with the browser.
Is there any method in selenium to avoid user interactions?

Please let me know if there are any other ways to show user those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not avoid user interaction in selenium. If you want to run your test in hidden mode, try with headless browser like phantomjs, htmlunit driver, etc. Otherwise you can in if clause to verify driver is null or not then call quit method.
Or you can take screenshot of result page and ask them to see the results.

Comment: can you please provide details on usage of verify driver method?

Comment: If(driver != null) driver.quit();